# Moving OpenGL objects with fingers

Tags: android, opengl-es, event-handling, java-native-interface

I'm developing an Android application with OpenGL and JNI (all OpenGL stuff is in C code).

Imagine I've drawn a cube. I want that user can push his finger over the cube and can rotate the cube and move it around the screen.

Is there any way to do that?

How can assign an event listener to touch and move events only when the user touch the cube?

**UPDATE**
 I want something like this:
[Rotate cube with fingers](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mmlbQJxX4I8)

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you doing this in C? I don't think that's how you're supposed to be using the opengl libs

Comment: C is faster than Java, and I need to use C. Because it is a requirement of the application.

Comment: C is a requirement of the application. I'm not optimizing, I'm following application requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called "picking" in 3d-ville...  There are a number of tutorials on the subject floating hither and yon.  There's even another question (sans the JNI spin) here on StackOverflow.

Also, check out [this google IO video](http://developer.android.com/videos/index.html#v=U4Bk5rmIpic) on developing android games to see why your approach may not be faster than pure Java... It Depends.

It turns out that JNI calls are Quite Expensive, so a JNI-based renderer could end up slower than a pure-java one unless you are Very Careful.  YM **Will** V.

I'm pretty sure you'll have to listen to all touches then change behavior based on what is being   touched.  I suppose you could compute your cube's bounding box on screen and then monkey with your listeners every frame (or every time it moves), but I seriously doubt that would be the most efficient course to take.  Listen for all touches, react appropriately.